# Set my own rule of converting char array to String in Java

Tags: java

I am actually writing a program to generate some truely random numbers. So, i am trying to write an algorithm to calculate from various factor.And i want to define my own encoding, so that when it is converted, it can only be strings of certain characters.

for example, the user wants only small letters, so i want something like this:

```
char[] result;
String result = new String(result,"MY OWN ENCODING")
```

Is there a way ?

Thanks alot !

Comment: your question isn't clear to me

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. One thing is certain though: if you're dealing with numbers, a char array is the wrong type to use.

Comment: There's always a way with Java ;)

Comment: Generally its not possible to generate truly random numbers, only pseudo random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to create a converter class:

```
public class Converter {

  private String charset;
  public Converter(String charset) {this.charset = charset;}

  public char[] convert(char[] input) {

    char[] result = new char[input.length];
    // do your own magic
    return result;
  }
}
```

Once the magic converter logic is implemented and in place:

```
Converter converter = new Converter("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
char[] result = converter.convert(myCharArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what a "character encoding" is.

Character encodings, which you can specify as the second argument in the `String(byte[], String)` constructor, do not have anything to do with what you seem to have in mind.

A character encoding is what specifies how characters in a string are converted to raw bytes and vice versa. For example the ASCII encoding specifies that the a byte with the value 65 represents the character 'A', 66 is 'B' etc.

A character encoding is not something that you can use to "convert" or "encode" a `char[]` with into a String object, and is not something that can filter out for example non-lower-case characters or transform arbitrary characters to lower-case characters. Forget about character encodings for this purpose, because that's not what character encodings are for.

Just write some method that converts the output of your random generator to characters in a suitable range. Here's a simple example of a program that generates a string from random lower-case characters:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generate(10));
    }

    public static String generate(int len) {
        Random random = new Random();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            sb.append((char)('a' + random.nextInt(26)));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```